# mongoDB collection creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

i have a problem with adding a collection into my database in mongodb atlas.
I have managed to import this collection before but i accidentally deleted it and now i can't upload it again. **there is no error in my terminal.** There for i don't know what is wrong with my code.. (image of my code and terminal are attached below)

There is anyone who might know why is this can happen?

*EDIT*

I tried to open a new database and my all the collections was imported to it and once again, only the product collection doesn't

//////////////////////////////////

```
/* require('dotenv').config({ path: '/.env' }) */
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.env') })
console.dir(process.env.MONGO_URI)
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    console.log('MongoDB connection SUCCESS')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection FAIL')
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
console.dir(process.env.MONGO_URI)

module.exports = connectDB
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
require('dotenv').config()

const productsData = require('./data/products')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const Product = require('./models/product')

connectDB()

const importData = async () => {
  try {
    /*  Product.deleteMany({}) */
    Product.insertMany(productsData)
    console.dir('Data Imported Successfuly')

    process.exit()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    console.error('Error Ocured In Imported Data Process', error)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

importData()
```

my model schema

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const products = require('../data/products')
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  countInStock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema)
```

[my code and terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCWMC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Product.insertMany(productsData)` returns a promise, but you aren't waiting for that promise to finish before exiting the process. Add an `await` before it and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create your schema instead

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  countInStock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
Product.createCollection();
```

Comment: hi, thank u for your replay. i am using mongoose schema but unfortunately it didn't help for my problem

Comment: I actually don’t see anything causing that problem with the code you shared, check your Product model again and if you could share it it would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: hi, i edited my question and upload the model as well

Comment: You will need to export Product model to be able to use it in others files